# Resource not Found userKey Google Directory API using Service Account

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

Here is my credential built using service account,

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
             .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(httpTransport)

     .setServiceAccountId("xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
     .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))

     .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER))

     .build();
```

And all I am trying is to get a user, where User is   com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User

```
User u = null;
try {
    u = service.users().get("test@gmail.com").execute();
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return u.toPrettyString();
}
```

response returns with code 404 Resource not found?? Is it user need to be created? how to access any gmail user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already granted your service account [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation), you'll need to have it impersonate an admin account using `.setServiceAccountUser("admin@domain.com")` as shown in the [service account documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Service accounts are not themselves domain admins, so they need to impersonate one in order to use the Admin SDK APIs.

Comment: I have added service account user xxx@abc.wix.com

Comment: yes it did, here is I created Google Apps Admin account provided that admin email as service account user and also added client id in Apps Admin by following googletutorial